# How to pass data to another ViewController without using a button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I currently have this Swift code which does not pass the `int` value that is stored in score into `currentScore` and `higherScore` into `highScore`.  Both `currentScore` and `highScore` are both instantiated on `GameOverViewController`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "GameOverVC" {
        let svc: GameOverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! GameOverViewController
        score = svc.currentScore
        higherScore = svc.highScore
    }
}
```

I am currently using the storyboard to push to the next view.  Here is the push code.

```
if let resultController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameOverVC") as? GameOverViewController {
    self.presentViewController(resultController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

All the code compiles fine, so do I need to have a actual `UIButton` or is there something else I need to add into the method or into `GameOverViewCotroller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assign value is wrong way...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "GameOverVC" {
        let svc: GameOverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! GameOverViewController
        svc.currentScore = score //pass self.score to svc.currentScore
        svc.highScore = higherScore //pass self.higherScore to svc.currentScore
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed that and it still didn't pass anything.  Any suggestions it might be something to do with the segue identifier as I am using the storyboard ID.

Comment: Is it call correctly?And just print svc.currentScore  below that line and same for svc.highScore

Comment: Have you applied segue properly between 2 vc?Check all value whether it nil or not and also print currentScore  in viewdidload of GameOverViewController and in prepareForSegue

Comment: Just checked on that it is not printing anything, so it must not be getting called.

Comment: so are you reach to this code or complier doen't enter to code?

Comment: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GameOverVC", sender: self)..If you are calling it from button or tabledidselect or from any control's action

Comment: I have implemented in my demo code work perfect..You should check segue tutorial to learn more about same.

Answer (score 0):

just Revert and try you are not assigning values properly

```
 score = svc.currentScore
 higherScore = svc.highScore
```

to

```
  svc.currentScore = score 
  svc.highScore = higherScore
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna pass a image to do like this-
In prepareForSegue you can't access the @IBOutlets of the destination view controller because they haven't been set up yet. You should assign the image to a property of the destination view controller, and then move it into place in viewDidLoad:

In source view controller:

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

```
if segue.identifier == "toBrowsePage" {
    let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! ListPage
    dvc.myImage = postingImage.image
}
```

}
In destination view controller:

class ListPage: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var browsingImage: UIImageView!
    var myImage: UIImage!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    browsingImage.image = myImage
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger you segue via 2 methods

drag a button to your segue and trigger it that way in Interface builder

or in your view controller you can call

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GameOverVC", sender: self)
```